# Why data not showing in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, kotlin-coroutines, koin

I am developing a news app and I have implemented retrofit with Kotlin coroutines with ViewModel and Koin but in my TopHeadlinesFragment data not showing. I did not understand where I am making mistake

below my appModules.kt where I have implemented a network.

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

val appModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportNewsInterface = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { MainViewModel (newsRepository = get ())  }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

below NewsRepository.kt

```
interface NewsRepository {
    // Suspend is used to await the result from Deferred
    suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
}

class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface) : NewsRepository {
    override suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>> {

        return try {
            val result = sportNewsInterface.getNews()
            UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

below My NewsInterface

interface SportNewsInterface {

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
suspend fun getNews(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=espn&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getEspn(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=football-italia&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getFootballItalia(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-sport&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getBBCSport(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>
```

}

below my SportNewsResponse.kt

```
data class SportNewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

below Article.kt model class

```
data class Source(
    val id: Any?,
    val name: String
)
```

below TopHeadlinesFragment where data is not showing

```
class TopHeadlinesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var viewModel: MainViewModel? = null
    private lateinit var topHeadlinesAdapter: TopHeadlinesAdapter
    private   val newsRepository: NewsRepository by inject()



    //3
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_top_headlines
            , container, false
        )


        val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
        val pb = view.findViewById(R.id.pb) as ProgressBar
        topHeadlinesAdapter = TopHeadlinesAdapter(recyclerView.context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = topHeadlinesAdapter
        val param = newsRepository
        val factory = MainViewModelFactory(param)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        initViewModel()

        return view
    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel?.sportList?.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
            topHeadlinesAdapter.updateData(newList)
        })

        viewModel?.showLoading?.observe(this, Observer { showLoading ->
            pb.visibility = if (showLoading) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        })

        viewModel?.showError?.observe(this, Observer { showError ->
            (showError)
        })

        viewModel?.loadNews()
    }
}
```

below TopHeadlinesAdapter.kt

```
class TopHeadlinesAdapter(val context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<TopHeadlinesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {



private var articleList: List<Article> by Delegates.observable(emptyList()) { _, _, _ ->

    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_list, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return articleList.size
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.articleTitle.text = articleList.get(position).title
    holder.articleSourceName.text = articleList.get(position).source.name
    Picasso.get().load(articleList.get(position).urlToImage).into(holder.image)

    val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
    val output = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    var d = Date()
    try {
        d = input.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
    } catch (e: ParseException) {
        try {
            val fallback = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
            fallback.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            d = fallback.parse(articleList[5].publishedAt)
        } catch (e2: ParseException) {
            // TODO handle error
            val formatted = output.format(d)
            val timelinePoint = LocalDateTime.parse(formatted)
            val now = LocalDateTime.now()

            var elapsedTime = Duration.between(timelinePoint, now)

            println(timelinePoint)
            println(now)
            elapsedTime.toMinutes()

            holder.articleTime.text = "${elapsedTime.toMinutes()}"

        }
    }

}

fun updateData(newList: List<Article>) {
     articleList = newList
    Log.e("articleListSize",articleList?.size.toString())

}


class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

    val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    val articleTitle: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle)
    val articleSourceName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleSourceName)
    val imageCategory: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory)
    val articleTime: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.articleTime)

}
```

}

below my json response from server

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 38,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "cnbc",
                "name": "CNBC"
            },
            "author": "Holly Ellyatt",
            "title": "Russia is now not the only pressing issue that NATO has to deal with - CNBC",
            "description": "Heads of state and government are meeting in the U.K. this week for the 70th anniversary of the military alliance NATO.",
            "url": "https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/02/nato-summit-alliance-has-more-pressing-issues-than-russia-now.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106272467-1575218599700gettyimages-997112494.jpeg?v=1575218712",
            "publishedAt": "2019-12-02T07:39:00Z",
            "content": "US president Donald Trump is seen during his press conference at the 2018 NATO Summit in Brussels, Belgium on July 12, 2018.\r\nAs heads of state and government meet in the U.K. this week for the 70th anniversary of the military alliance NATO, discussions are l… [+8623 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Chron.com"
            },
            "author": "Aaron Wilson",
            "title": "Bill O'Brien gets game ball from Deshaun Watson after Texans' win over Patriots - Chron",
            "description": "In an emotional moment, Texans coach Bill O'Brien was presented with the game ball by quarterback Deshaun Watson following a pivotal win over the New England Patriots.",
            "url": "https://www.chron.com/sports/texans/article/Bill-O-Brien-Deshaun-Watson-Texans-Patriots-14874678.php",
            "urlToImage": "https://s.hdnux.com/photos/01/07/23/50/18692664/3/rawImage.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2019-12-02T06:16:00Z",
            "content": "<ul><li>Houston Texans head coach Bill O'Brien on the sidelines during the fourth quarter of an NFL game against the New England Patriots at NRG Stadium Sunday, Dec. 1, 2019, in Houston.\r\nHouston Texans head coach Bill O'Brien on the sidelines during the four… [+1583 chars]"


        }
    ]
}
```

below My MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel(newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
     val job = Job()
     val sportNewsInterface: SportNewsInterface? = null
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

     val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
     val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()



    fun loadNews(

    ) {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                sportNewsInterface?.getNews()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `MainViewModel` code

Comment: @StanislavShamilov, I have added MainViewModel.kt please check it

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen in your code in `MainViewModel`, you're trying to get results from the variable `sportNewsInterface`:

```
val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   sportNewsInterface?.getNews()
}
```

This variable is initialized with `null` and never gets initialized after. I suppose it's a typo mistake and you should have used `newsRepository.getNewsList()` instead.

Add `val` before `newsRepository` in the `MainViewModel`'s costructor, so the variable will become a member of the class and use it instead of `sportNewsInterface` in the method `loadNews()`.

**Update**

The author updated his code and send the updated version using a gist file: https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/9f0e1eb8696e4b88a354e8a372a8e690

Having revived your code, you have to add several changes:

- Class `TopHeadlinesFragment`

First of all, the viewmodel variable there is not initialized. Since you're providing it using Koin, change the line 3 with this code: 
`private var viewModel by viewModel<MainViewModel>()`

- File `NewsRepository.kt`, class `NewsRepositoryImpl`.

This is where the circular dependency is. If you'll look at the constructor of `NewsRepositoryImpl`, you'll notice that this class takes an argument of type `NewsRepository`. This actually makes a circular dependency since this type both already exists and being provided in the `appModules` Koin module. Having that said, you should just replaced that parameter with an instance of `SportNewsInterface`, so the class `NewsRepositoryImpl` will look like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class NewsRepositoryImpl(private val sportsNewsApi: SportNewsInterface) : NewsRepository {
    override suspend fun getNewsList(): UseCaseResult<List<Article>> {

        return try {
            val result = sportsNewsApi.getNews()
            UseCaseResult.Success(result) as UseCaseResult<List<Article>>
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            UseCaseResult.Error(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

- Class `MainViewModel`

Here you should delete the line 5 `val newsRepository: NewsRepository? = null` since you already have that dependency at the class's constructor as a parameter. Besides that, in order to make the parameter into the field, add `val` before that. As a result, you code will look like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newsRepository?.getNewsList()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented as you told me but app crashes

Comment: Send the crash log

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kyodgorbek/9f0e1eb8696e4b88a354e8a372a8e690 my log

Comment: It seems that you've got a circular dependency. It would be easier to help you if you update your post with the updated code or create a gist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203779/discussion-between-sashabeliy-and-stanislav-shamilov).